# If an enum's case has an associated type, is it possible to get the case name without the associated data?

Tags: swift, enums, case

Given this code...

```swift
enum Label {
    case barcode(String)
    case qrRCode(String)
}

let label:Label = .barcode("barcode data")

print("The label's type is '\(label)'")
```

It prints

> The label's type is 'barcode("barcode data")'

I'm trying to figure out how to print only

> The label's type is 'barcode'

Is there a way to do that outside of writing a computed property with hardcoded strings to match the case types or manually trimming up to the opening paren?

Comment: Please refer this. This is exactly what you are looking for- [https://medium.com/@PhiJay/why-swift-enums-with-associated-values-cannot-have-a-raw-value-21e41d5ec11]

Comment: Link says 'not found'.  Plus, it's considered good etiquette on SO to post the content here along with the link, specifically for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The string you're looking for is represented by the label of the only [mirror child](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror/child) of an enumeration case with an associated value.

```swift
protocol CaseNameWithoutAssociatedValueStringConvertible: CustomStringConvertible { }

extension CaseNameWithoutAssociatedValueStringConvertible {
  var description: String {
    Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first!.label!
  }
}
```

```swift
extension Label: CaseNameWithoutAssociatedValueStringConvertible { }

"\( Label.barcode("️‍♂️") )" // "barcode"
"\( Label.qrRCode("‍☠️") )" // "qrRCode"
```